# Errors when trying to deploy a react website with firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

every time I run "npm run deploy:development" I get this:

```
   MacBook-Pro:frontend eug$ npm run deploy:development

> app-frontend@0.1.0 deploy:development /Users/eugenebv/Documents/PetHotel/frontend
> firebase use development && cross-env REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=development npm run build && firebase deploy --only hosting,storage

sh: firebase: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! app-frontend@0.1.0 deploy:development: `firebase use development && cross-env REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=development npm run build && firebase deploy --only hosting,storage`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app-frontend@0.1.0 deploy:development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have firebase and firebase-tools installed, although i see "firebase: command not found".
I ran the alias command to set firebase, whenever I run any firebase command, it works.

Comment: Could be that the alias is not defined in the sh subshell that's spawned by npm. If you install `firebase-tools` via npm either globally or as a dev dependency in the project, does it work?

Comment: @cubrr it's installed globally. I installed it again now and still the same.